# Remove Quicklook Syntax Highlighting with TextMate2?

Tags: quicklook, textmate, sublimetext, highlights

TextMate2 Alpha comes with a Syntax Highlighting plugin for macOS QuickLook.

How can it be disabled without removing TextMate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can run

```
rm -r /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/Library/QuickLook/TextMateQL.qlgenerator
```

but you'll have to do that again every time TextMate is updated.